# Verify a Stack Overflow user via OpenID?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, openid

I'm not all that familiar with OpenID, so this very well could be a Stack Overflow / technical question, but... is there a way to verify someone's Stack Overflow account using their OpenID?

I have an openID URL on my account that's something like www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx... if someone could verify that my OpenID URL on StackOverflow is *actually* that, would that make a difference?

I understand that this is a possible duplicate, as Kevin inquired about [Verifying a user (mainly at an interview)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7851/verifying-a-user-mainly-at-an-interview) (to which the answer was "have them write some text on Stack Overflow"), but... slightly different angle here.

Comment: This is a lot more specific to one method of verification, so I'd judge it not a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the context?

Are you just trying to determine automatically whether a given openid url or which from a set of openid urls are valid stackoverflow users, and what their stackoverflow id is?  If so, I don't think that's possible without asking the StackOverflow database itself in some way.

Are you serving a page to a user and asking them to prove stackoverflow membership by signing into an open id account, where you'll know whether the url they use belongs to a valid stackoverflow user?  If so, you might have more luck.  Unfortunately there's a big exception for google, since they use a different unique url per site (something Jeff & co taught us when adding more sites after Stackoverflow.com) and so the google openid for your site wouldn't match the id from stackoverflow.

If this is in reference to finding a better way to do verification for the telerik promotion, you might need to open up a web service on StackOverflow that telerik can call directly.

Comment: You got it: I was mostly thinking for the Telerik promotion (or something similar). I'm not too worried about it, since the 10K club is pretty small, but it'd be nice to know how we could do it should it become an issue. The back-up idea is, in the event of suspicious activty, we ask the account holder to publish a key on his profile or something.